# Compare two columns which is list with n number of values and save the data as a list in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to perform comparison operation (like greater than or less than) on two columns which is list with n number of values (values are nothing but timestamp) and my result should also be in list.

How can I do this operation?

Input:

```
Date1                                         Date2
["2016-11-24 12:06:47"]                       ["2017-10-04 03:30:23"]
["null"]                                      []
["2017-01-25 10:07:25","2018-01-25 10:07:25"] ["2017-09-15 03:30:16","2017-09-15 03:30:16"]
```

Output should be:

```
Result
["Less"]
["Not Okay"]
["Less","Great"]
```

Comment: Can you share some input and output data and what have you tried so far?

Comment: My Input Data is like:
Date1   ["2016-11-24 12:06:47"]  ["null"] ["2017-01-25 10:07:25","2018-01-25 10:07:25"]  Which is a column..This should be compare with  Date2  ["2017-10-04 03:30:23"] []   ["2017-09-15 03:30:16","2017-09-15 03:30:16"]

Comment: Can you update in the question with input and result rather than in comment ?

Comment: You can write an udf which takes two column as input and compare the two columns. And what if the size of array is different ?

Comment: Array of size will be same almost..As i am new to this technology, i dont know what methods will be useful for getting this.

Comment: Before exploring the "Not Okay" implementation with `RegEx`, are you sure you would expect `Less, Less, Great` instead of `Less, Great, Great`? Please see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to perform comparison operation

It seems you are looking for the `.compareTo` operator:

```
scala> "a".compareTo("b")
res: Int = -1

scala> "a".compareTo("a")
res: Int = 0

scala> "b".compareTo("a")
res: Int = 1
```

Using the first example mentioned:

```
val date1 = "2016-11-24 12:06:47"
val date2 = "2017-10-04 03:30:23"

scala> date1.compareTo(date2)
res: Int = -1
```

If we ignore for a moment the `"Not Okay"` case, we could implement the `"Less"` or `"Great"` cases with a function like:

```
def compareLexicographically(s1: String, s2: String): String = s1.compareTo(s2) match {
  case -1 => "Less"
  case _  => "Great"
}
```

Looking at your example, I am assuming the rows are tuples of list of Strings:

```
val rows: List[(List[String], List[String])] = 
List((
  List("2016-11-24 12:06:47"),
  List("2017-10-04 03:30:23")
),
(
  List("2017-01-25 10:07:25", "2018-01-25 10:07:25"),
  List("2017-09-15 03:30:16", "2017-09-15 03:30:16")
))
```

I would first `zip` the elements from the columns to get `List[(String, String)]`

```
rows.flatMap(r => r._1.zip(r._2))
```

Then simple `map` with `compareLexicographically`:

```
scala> rows.flatMap(r => r._1.zip(r._2)).map((compareLexicographically _).tupled)
res: List[String] = List(Less, Great, Great)
```

Comment: This is okay. But what i receive is a Dataframe and then i am taking two columns from it. So it will have multiple rows. I cannot manually add them to list.